# Differentiability of $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to show that the function $x^\frac{1}{n}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ is differentiable for all $x>0$

Let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{+*}$

$\cfrac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=\cfrac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}-{x_{0}}^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x-x_{0}}$

I don't know where to go from there, I need some kind of algebraic manipulation in order to take the limit. Any tips?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Does it really matter? And if it does matter, how is $(x+h)^{1/n}$ more convenient?

Comment: Sometimes it is. I thought it might be the case here. I accidentally deemed my comment instead of editing it.

Comment: @Arthur I don't think so, as $(x+h)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}$ contains more character than $x^{1/n}-x_0^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $x,x_0$ strictly positive, we have
$$
x-x_0=(x^{1/n})^n-(x_0^{1/n})^n=\cdots
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may use that, for $n=2,3,\cdots$,
$$
a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$x - x_0 = (x^{1/n})^n-(x_0^{1/n})^n = (x^{1/n} - x_0^{1/n})((x^{1/n})^{n-1} + (x^{1/n})^{n-2} (x_0^{1/n})^1 + \dots + (x_0^{1/n})^{n-1}),$$
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=\frac{x^{1/n}-{x_{0}}^{1/n}}{x-x_{0}}=\frac{1}{(x^{1/n})^{n-1} + (x^{1/n})^{n-2} (x_0^{1/n})^1 + \dots + (x_0^{1/n})^{n-1}},$$
so $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=\frac{1}{(x^{1/n})^{n-1} + (x^{1/n})^{n-2} (x_0^{1/n})^1 + \dots + (x_0^{1/n})^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{n x_0^{(n-1)/n}}.$$